# Programming a game using the Javafx class from a tutorial and have come across an undefined class error

Tags: java, eclipse, awt

```
else if(left || right) {
    if(currentAction != WALKING) {
        currentAction = WALKING;
        animation.setFrames(sprites.get(WALKING));
        animation.setDelay(40);
        width = 30;
```

Here is the code I am having issues with. namely the `animation.setFrames` and `setDelay` the `setFrames` uses a `BufferedImage` array and the `setDelay` is a `long` variable. The two errors that come up are

```
The method setFrames(BufferedImage[]) is undefined for the type Animation
```

and

```
The method setDelay(Duration) in the type Animation is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

```
public void setFrames(BufferedImage[] frames) {
        this.frames = frames;
        currentFrame = 0;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        playedOnce = false;
```

this is the code for the `setFrames` and the code of `delay`'s setter is just

```
public void setDelay(long d) {
    delay = d;
}
```

Any assistance is welcome.
There were none of these errors in the tutorial
EDIT: I have created a new `Animation` class in the constructor but it did not solve it. Added Animation class

```
  package Entity;

    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    public class Animation {
        private BufferedImage[] frames;
        private int currentFrame;

        private long startTime;
        private long delay;

        private boolean playedOnce; played; e.g. an attack so it does not


        public void Animation() {
            playedOnce = false;
        }

        public void setFrames(BufferedImage[] frames) {
            this.frames = frames;
            currentFrame = 0;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            playedOnce = false;
        }

        public void setDelay(long d) {
            delay = d;
        }

        public void setFrame(int i) {
            currentFrame = i;
        }

        public void update() {
            if (delay == -1)
                return;
            long elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
            if (elapsed > delay) {
                currentFrame++;
                playedOnce = true;

            }

        }

        public int getFrame() {
            return currentFrame;
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage() {
            return frames[currentFrame];
        }

        public boolean hasPlayedOnce() {
            return playedOnce;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you are not importing the Animation class from javafx.animation.
 Remove this line if you find it in your imports: import javafx.animation.Animation.

 If that doesn't fix it, please post your entire Animation class.

Comment: Show us an [mcve]

Comment: Using `BufferedImage` in a JavaFX project seems a bit strange. Usually `BufferedImage` is used with Swing/AWT projects; JavaFX projects usually use `javafx.scene.image.Image`. Furthermore the class hierarchy seems important here. It looks like you're using `javafx.animation.Animation` without extending it. This way your custom methods are unavailable, so where did you put them?

Comment: The class the errors are occurring extends a super abstract class. The methods that are causing problems did not cause any issues in the tutorial where the Animation class was not extended in this class.

Comment: Fixed thank you for the support, I just need to create a new animation

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Bandreid for the answer. 
It need the object to be added and a new object created.